# Set a string on a string referenced by string array

Tags: c#, string

```
string db;
ComboBox fieldBox = new ComboBox()
TextBox ValueBox = new TextBox()
ListBox dbValues = new ListBox()

private void LoadDB()
{
    //Structure
    string myStruct = "NAME\nAGE\nSEX\nSKILL
    db = "John\t20\tMale\tNoob\n
                   Joe\t20\tMale\tMedium\n
                   Jessica\t27\tFemale\tExpert\n
                   John\t21\tMale\tMedium
                  ";

    //Load struct to combobox
    string[] mbstr = myStruct.Split('\n');
    for (int i = 0; i < mbstr.Length; i++)
    {
        fieldBox.Items.Add(mbstr[i]);
    }

    string[] db2 = db.Split('\n');
    for (int i = 1; i < db2.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        //Display name and age in combobox
        dbValues.Items.Add(db2[i].Split('\t')[0] + " - " +   db2[i].Split('\t')[1]);
    }
}

void ValueBoxKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.KeyCode != Keys.Enter)
        return;

    db.Split('\n')[dbValues.SelectedIndex].Split('\t')[fieldBox.SelectedIndex] = valueBox.Text;

    MessageBox.Show("Value set: " +
                           db.Split('\n')[dbValues.SelectedIndex + 1].Split('\t')[fieldBox.SelectedIndex]
                            + " to " + valueBox.Text + ".");
}
```

This is where it fails:

```
db.Split('\n')[dbValues.SelectedIndex].Split('\t')[fieldBox.SelectedIndex] = valueBox.Text;
```

I tried this, and tried to assign to db, but not working though. My original string is unchanged.

I do not want to convert to list and string back, i want to change directly.
How can i do this?

Comment: What is the result that you get?

Comment: What is the output you want?

Comment: Apparently from your code, the words withitn the string is neither split by \n nor by \t

Comment: I think split function will not return reference, rather it returns new string.You could try string replace..

Comment: You cannot change it, you will have to re-create a new string, because strings are immutable.

Comment: Can you please edit the questions accorinf to all those comments? What you actually want and what you get instead. Thus we may reopen the question and you´d get better answers probably.

Comment: @BG101 - he said basically that in the comments below. This guy is obviously pretty new to both programming and StackOverflow, I'm just trying to help him out. I actually, correctly as it turns out, thought that is what he was going for when I read the question begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is your string: unless you use @ escaping you can't have your string cross multiple lines, and if you use @ escaping you can't do \t or \n and retain their escaped meaning of tab and newline.

The second problem is a fundamental misunderstanding of the .NET string, string's are immutable. Split will create an array, there is no reference back to the original string, or the second array your splitting. You would need to do something like:

```
[TestClass]
public class StringTest
{
    public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }
    [TestMethod]
    public void RewriteString()
    {
        var str = "Garry\t19\tMale\tNoob\n" +
            "Joe\t25\tMale\tMedium\n" +
            "Gary\t33\tFemale\tExpert";

        var rows = str.Split('\n');
        var columns = rows[0].Split('\t');
        columns[0] = "Jerry";
        rows[0] = string.Join("\t", columns);
        str = string.Join("\n", rows);
        TestContext.WriteLine(str);
    }
}
 Test Name: RewriteString
 Test Outcome:  Passed
 Result StandardOutput: TestContext Messages:
 Jerry  19  Male    Noob
 Joe    25  Male    Medium
 Gary   33  Female  Expert
```

Would really hope there would be an easier way to do this, possibly with a Regex?

Now to really look at your (new) question. I have refactored exactly what you have, as I do not know your data situation I'm not entirely sure using a string as a database is a good idea: (this will compile without any references because of the use of dynamic).

```
public class SomeView
{
    string db;
    dynamic fieldBox = null;
    dynamic valueBox = null;
    dynamic dbValues = null;
    dynamic MessageBox = null;
    private void LoadDB()
    {
        //Structure
        string myStruct = "NAME\nAGE\nSEX\nSKILL";
        db = "John\t20\tMale\tNoob\n" +
                       "Joe\t20\tMale\tMedium\n" +
                       "Jessica\t27\tFemale\tExpert\n" +
                       "John\t21\tMale\tMedium";

        //Load struct to combobox
        string[] mbstr = myStruct.Split('\n');
        for (int i = 0; i < mbstr.Length; i++)
        {
            fieldBox.Items.Add(mbstr[i]);
        }

        string[] db2 = db .Split('\n');
        for (int i = 1; i < db2.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            var data = db2[i].Split('\t'); //expensive only do once
            //Display name and age in combobox
            dbValues.Items.Add(data[0] + " - " + data[1]);
        }
    }
    protected string Transform(string value, int row, int column, string replacement, out string old)
    {
        var rows = value.Split('\n');
        var columns = rows[row].Split('\t');
        old = columns[column];
        columns[column] = replacement;
        rows[row] = string.Join("\t", columns);
        return string.Join("\n", rows);
    }
    void ValueBoxKeyDown(object sender, dynamic e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode != "enter")
            return;
        string old;
        string newValue = this.Transform(db, dbValues.SelectedIndex, fieldBox.SelectedIndex, valueBox.Text, out old);

        MessageBox.Show("Value set: " + old + " to " + valueBox.Text + ".");
    }
}
```

So this is better:

```
public class SomeView
{
    dynamic fieldBox = null;
    dynamic valueBox = null;
    dynamic dbValues = null;
    dynamic MessageBox = null;
    private List<Person> People = new List<Person>();
    private void LoadDB()
    {
        //Structure
        string myStruct = "NAME\nAGE\nSEX\nSKILL";
        string db = "John\t20\tMale\tNoob\n" +
                       "Joe\t20\tMale\tMedium\n" +
                       "Jessica\t27\tFemale\tExpert\n" +
                       "John\t21\tMale\tMedium";
        //Load struct to combobox
        string[] mbstr = myStruct.Split('\n');
        for (int i = 0; i < mbstr.Length; i++)
        {
            fieldBox.Items.Add(mbstr[i]);
        }
        People.Clear();
        foreach(var row in db.Split('\n'))
        {
            var columns = row.Split('\t');
            Person p = new Person();
            p.Name = columns[0];
            p.Age = int.Parse(columns[1]);
            p.Sex = (Person.Sexs)Enum.Parse(typeof(Person.Sexs), columns[2]);
            p.SkillLevel = (Person.SkillLevels)Enum.Parse(typeof(Person.SkillLevels), columns[2]);
            People.Add(p);
            dbValues.Items.Add(string.Format("{0}-{1}", p.Name, p.Age);
        }
    }
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public enum Sexs
        {
            Male,
            Female
        }
        public Sexs Sex { get; set; }
        public enum SkillLevels
        {
            Noob,
            Medium,
            Expert
        }
        public SkillLevels SkillLevel { get; set; }
    }
    void ValueBoxKeyDown(object sender, dynamic e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode != "enter")
            return;
        Person p = this.People[dbValues.SelectedIndex];
        switch((int)fieldBox.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 0: p.Name = valueBox.Text; break;
            case 1: p.Age = int.Parse(valueBox.Text); break;
            case 2: p.Sex = (Person.Sexs)Enum.Parse(typeof(Person.Sexs), valueBox.Text); break;
            case 3: p.SkillLevel = (Person.SkillLevels)Enum.Parse(typeof(Person.SkillLevels), valueBox.Text); break;
            default: throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Value set: " + old + " to " + valueBox.Text + ".");
    }
}
```

However this is still garbage, since if you have a strongly typed data set you can actually bind this to form controls without directly manipulating the item.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8aebh9k(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @HimBromBeere: forget to Join on \n and \t

Comment: Thank you for marking this as the answer, it probably is easier to work with and understand than the Regex solution, however unless you need greater flexibility over which ordinal word(s) to replace the Regex solution is going to perform better.

Comment: @JasonLindI Thought it worked, but not, i marked to soon...Recheck my question

Comment: @MiguelSilva your question turned out to be a two parter, I assumed your string was pseudo-code, my bad

Comment: @MiguelSilva: I've updated it, I highly advise against using the first solution as treating a string like a database is a VERY bad idea. If you have to use a string as the database (reading tab delimited maybe?) there are really good parser libraries out there to help you, my second solution is pretty quick and dirty. Either way I would advise against directly manipulating items like that (and use DataBinding), and also you should look into using a UI pattern to separate your data, business and ui logic. Model-View-Presenter is very popular for Windows Forms. Last WinForms is kind of dead, WPF

Comment: This did the job, im gonna use your first example because its more than good for me, thank you and thanks HimBromBeere for helping and sorry for the messe, it was simple but i did it complicated...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the return-value of a method returning a string as strings are immutable. What you can do instead is the following:

```
string myDatabase = 
    "Garry\t19\tMale\tNoob\n" +
    "Joe\t25\tMale\tMedium\n" +
    "Gary\t33\tFemale\tExpert";

var tmp = "";
foreach(var line in myString.Split('\n')) {
    tmp = tmp + Regex.Replace(line, "^.*?(?=\\t)", myReplaceText);
}
myString = tmp;
```

This regex will search for everything before the very first tab within every line, replaces it by `"Jerry"`and and concatenates every so replaced line into `myString`.

Comment: This is not the same as the original code, as you could end up with multiple replacements depending on the string content

Comment: @JasonLind I know, but as he wants to split by "\n" so I supposed that he actually wants a string containing several newline-statements. However I CANNOT determine that there are more occurences within the search-string neither from the code nor from any comment.

Comment: @HimBromBeere that replaces all, i want to replace just that string

Comment: @MiguelSilva Which is "that string". What part to you want to replace by wihich?

Comment: @HimBromBeree I want to replace 'THIS'  by 'NOTHING',  without altering anything else,  but by the way i mentioned in the code

Comment: Not explicitely as there are no tabs within your code where you may split. However I change it to something more appriprioate.

Comment: Now it should work. Notice that I changed the input-strings to contain tabs instead of some spaces. Now `Split("\n")` will split at the word-boundaries.

Comment: Yes buy if i have another 'THIS'  it replaces all,  i want to replace just that one, thats why i reference by array using Split, and im using values like a data base, so i cant use regex way you posted

Comment: The regex will actually only look for the very first word which is indicated by the proceeding `^`.

Comment: The regex is def the best option, assuming he always wants the first, and only the first word. If there is some algorithmic determination of which word(s) to replace then formulating a regex on the fly, while possible, might not be the most practical approach.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Re-check my question now

Comment: That shouldn´t change anything to the algo I posted. Solution should still work except that you now replace with "Jerry" instead with "NOTHING".

Comment: But if you wanted to replace the second line, first word, you would have to have a very different Regex where as with the solution I proposed you would just have to assign arry1[1] instead of arry1[0]. This Regex solution is both less code and will perform faster, the question is if you need more flexibility than Regex can easily provide.

Comment: @HimBromBeere: if I were you I'd delete everything but your RegEx solution, as the first part of your answer really doesn't solve the use case

Comment: @JasonLind While this is undoubtly true OP sayed he only need the very first word.

Comment: JasonLind Is right, thats what i mean, thats why i split in the code, i could need to change another line, that why i split it

Comment: Okay, what exactly is your question? Do you want to replace the very first word of the entire string or the first word per line?

Comment: @HimBromBeere: I'd be really curious to see function taking in an ordinal row and column and produce a regex that allows him to target that specific pair. Also you should note I don't think your regex would work as stated as Jason Lind\t31\tMale\tExpert\n is a perfectly valid row, and your regex (from my understanding) would just replace Jason and not Jason Lind

Comment: @JasonLind And again this is nothing the OP mentions in his question. Please stop maling assumptions on what OP MAY have asked for, it has a reason the question is marked as unclear. Also your edit to the question is made uppon that assumption.

Comment: @HimBromBeere: "JasonLind Is right, thats what i mean, thats why i split in the code, i could need to change another line, that why i split it – Miguel Silva" That's why I edited it, because clearly that's what he's asking. It might not be clear to you, but I was able to derive exactly what he was going for when he asked the question. I deal with a lot of offshore code written by junior developers who don't speak very good English, I'm just trying to help a guy out.

Comment: Im really sorry for both you guys, im really bad today, im not really new on c#, but yes to StackOverflow, but im having a mad day.. Now my code is understandable, please read and im sorry...

Comment: Completely edited my answer to fit your needs

Comment: Still didn't *quite* get it, he needs to replace specific line and a specific column.